# Does the Otyugh's Tentacle attack allow a saving throw to avoid being grappled if the attack hits?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, grapple

Per the Monster Manual's statblock for the Otyugh (pg 248), a successful tentacle attack results in the following:

> If the target is Medium or smaller, it is grappled (escape DC13) and
>   restrained until the grapple ends.

Does the target get a chance to do a save of some kind to avoid being grappled in the first place? I am aware that the target can use an action to escape after being grappled, but is there any way a Medium or smaller creature can avoid being grappled on a successful hit with a tentacle attack?